# What is the XML command used to open a SWF?

Tags: xml

I purchased a portfolio gallery online. The code is in HTML, JavaScript, and XML. I am suppose to be able to select an icon and a lightbox image opens to reveal the selected item. The gallery is also suppose allow an icon to play a SWF file as well. I have successfully integrated my images into the gallery however I can not get the .swf files to play. I tried to just insert my .swf file structure and file name into the example however that did not work. Given the XML code provided below of the example of a working loading .swf file. Can someone tell me the proper code to make mine play.

Also is it possible to have a the website open up on click also? What would that code look like?

I also provided the link to the portfolio demo to give a demo of how it works.

http://codecanyon.net/item/tonic-gallery-jQuery-xml-portfolio-gallery/full_screen_preview/120710 (demo)

My file structure leading to my .swf file is images/psst.swf my file size is 550x400

My XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portfolio>

<categories>
<category id="graphic">Graphic Design</category>
<category id="web">Web Design</category>
<category id="photo">Photography</category>
<category id="video">Videos</category>
</categories>

<item>
    <thumbnail>images/img1.jpg</thumbnail>
    <preview>images/preview.jpg</preview>
    <category>graphic,web,photo</category>
    <description>Description goes here</description>
</item>

         <item>
    <thumbnail>images/img3.jpg</thumbnail>
    <preview>http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&   amp;height=294</preview>
    <category>video</category>
    <description>Flash video preview</description>
</item>
```

Comment: What image gallery? Just like what example? Please include more context :-)

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "an XML command"

Comment: @cameron- I reposted what I rewrote today. I included the link to the demo. I did paste a sample of the code at the bottom. I am uncertain if you saw that but the second set of item's has an adobe flash player example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous answer, i didnt understand exactly what you were trying to do.

I looked the xml ( http://pexeto.com/tonic_gallery/portfolio.xml ) on the gallery site http://pexeto.com/tonic_gallery/ you can check out the code. The flash part looks like this on the working example:

```
<item>
    <thumbnail>images/flash.jpg</thumbnail>
    <preview>http://www.adobe.com/jp/events/cs3_web_edition_tour/swfs/perform.swf?width=792&height=294</preview>
    <category>video</category>
    <description>Flash video preview</description>
</item>
```

So i think that your problem is the space and &amp in the preview field url, try with "&" so:

```
<preview>http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&height=294</preview>
```

instead of:

```
<preview>http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/include/marquee/design.swf?width=792&   amp;height=294</preview>
```